# Include jquery library in PWA Venia setup

Tags: jquery, pwa, venia, react, react-js

We mentioned jquery library file in template.html in PWA Venia setup as below :

```
  <script async src="//asset.fwcdn3.com/js/embed-feed.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

We are using that library file in below path

**src/components/Homepage/components** - FireWork.js

```
import React from "react";
import HeadTitle from './HeadTitle';

const FireWork = () => {
return(
<div class="">
<HeadTitle title={'Shop By Look'} textAlign={'center'} />

<fw-embed-feed
channel="glow"
autoplay="true">
</fw-embed-feed>
<br/>


</div>
);
}

export default FireWork;
```

**Issue** :

It's working fine. but is it wrong to insert a jquery library file directly in a template.html file? do we need use **import** ? so i tried as below :

I created new file : initialize-fire.js

```
const initializeFire = () => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//asset.fwcdn3.com/js/embed-feed.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = scriptOnLoad;
    document.body.append(script);
};
```

and inserted the below line in firework.js :

```
import { initializeFire } from '../../initialize-fire.js';
```

but it giving error : **module not found**

Firework.js : https://pastebin.com/utfXgFLc

Comment: Have you checked this path is correct '../../initialize-fire.js'

Comment: please check here : https://prnt.sc/VlTbJ64hsxX6 , `initialize-fire.js` located in `src` folder

Comment: yes not sure but i think this is wrong maybe

Comment: below `initialize-fire.js` , you can see `initialize-netcore.js` , that is working fine

Comment: please join : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151831/magento-pwa

Comment: Okay but we need to check what is wrong with that without checking we can not get a proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your FierWork.js file please add the external js code like this into the file, here do not import another file for only one js script.

please replace your FierWork.js file code with this code.

```
import React from "react";
import HeadTitle from './HeadTitle';

// Create the function
export function AddLibrary(urlOfTheLibrary) {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = urlOfTheLibrary;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

const FireWork = () => {

    return(
        <div class="">
            <HeadTitle title={'Shop By Look'} textAlign={'center'} />
            {AddLibrary(
                "https://asset.fwcdn3.com/js/storyblock.js"
            )}
          
            <fw-storyblock
             channel="glow"
             playlist="oBRmRo"
             autoplay="true">
            </fw-storyblock>
            <br/>
         </div>
    );
}

export default FireWork;
```

Please accept my answer if this is work for you.
Thanks.